# Upload Image in node js and send it to the Python code

Tags: python, node.js, file-upload

I'm new to node js now.
I want to upload an image and sent the image to grayscale.py.
And then I want to display grayscaled image to the browser.
But It Doesn't Work!
I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
``
app.post("/api/images", upload.single("imageFile"), async (req, res) => {`this is server code to upload image to node js server`
  if (req.file) {
    const filePath = "http://localhost:3000/image/" + req.file.originalname;
    newInfo["imageFile"] = filePath;
  }

  const member = { ...newInfo, id: Date.now() };
  members.push(member);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/api/images/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const member = members.find((m) => m.id === +id);
  if (!member || !member.imageFile) {
    res.status(404).send("Image not found");
    return;
  }
  res.send(member);
});

app.get("/api/grayscale/:id", async (req, res) => { `this is server code to send image to the python code`
  const { id } = req.params;
  const member = members.find((m) => m.id === +id);

  if (!member || !member.imageFile) {
    res.status(404).send("Image not found");
    return;
  }

  const pythonProcess = spawn("python", [pythonScriptPath, ...pythonArgs]);

  pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {

    const imageData = Buffer.from(data, "base64");

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" });
    res.end(imageData);
  });

  pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
``
```

this is my server code

[this is showImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX1rQ.png)
``
runBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
const filePath = images[currentIndex].name;

```
axios.get('/api/grayscale', {
    params: {
        filePath: filePath
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        const b64Data = btoa(
            new Uint8Array(response.data)
                .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
        );
        const url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64Data;
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = url;
        imgViewR.innerHTML = '';
        imgViewR.appendChild(img);
```

});
``
And this is my client code.
Thank you for your help

I tried axios, multer, pyshell ... but everything doesn't work